# How do I tell Visual Studio Code where my include directories are for a C project?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a C project that I develop on Mac. I'm considering ditching Eclipse and switching to VS Code. The project uses Makefiles and I have about 40 directories I need on the include path from an SDK and the gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain.

Ideally, I'd like VS Code to be able to read these Makefiles and figure out where to find stuff so that I don't have to duplicate this information between the Makefiles themselves, which are the real source of truth, and some sort of settings.json stuff, which are not. However, I accept it's early days for the C/C++ extension and that might be ambitious. If I have to replicate a bunch of stuff in the workspace settings.json for the project, I'm happy with that for now.

So, how do I set this up? My end goal is that I can hit F12 on a function name and go to the definition when that definition is in an #include'ed source.

Comment: Oh, and I'm aware of this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscppsamples/issues/18